# How can I add domain specific vocabulary to Text Analytics?

Tags: text-analytics-api

The Cognitive services Text Analytics API does not find domain specific keywords. Is there a way to provide a supplemental list of words that text analytics will use when analyzing text?

For example in the sentence below the keywords "Intramolecular", "ionic", "covalent", "intermolecular" are not recognized.

"Which type of bonds are involved when matter changes state between solid, liquid, and gas? Intramolecular, ionic, covalent, intermolecular."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, there is no way to provide your own vocabulary. That said, you can vote for this feature [here](https://cognitive.uservoice.com/forums/555922-text-analytics).